# Perspective transform doesn't scale when the width scales?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I resize the browser so that the height is smaller, the picture stays perfectly scaled and in the right place. However, if I resize the browser so that the width is smaller, the pictures move and it doesn't not scale properly.

I'm using the perspective transform on the second container that will contain the image: 
`transform: translate(-50%, -50%) perspective(1000px) rotateY(50deg);`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/a7kw47pg/1/

If I create an html file with that code and run it on my browser, I can't see the first "t" on the watermark. However, when I resize the width of the browser so that it's smaller, I am able to see the "t". I want it so that no matter what size the browser is, I will not be able to see the "t" (basically the rotated picture with the perspective to stay locked on that exact spot).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it scales differently is because all the original div positions are scaling on a **proportional** basis while the transform perspective changes on an **absolute** basis. The perspective value can be thought of as the number of pixels of distance from the viewer's eye to the screen. Any 3D rotation will of course make your image smaller (in this case it's only horizontal because you've only rotated about the vertical axis). When your imaginary eye is a fixed distance from the screen (in this case 1000px), then you see a smaller relative perspective-effect when the image is small and a larger relative perspective effect when the image is large. (Imagine standing 1 meter away from a huge building - the perspective effect is crazy. But now imagine standing 1 meter away from a little 1-cm cube - it basically looks the same as it does from 1km away)

In order to keep the horizontal size of the image constant, you need to **dynamically modify the perspective distance** as the window size changes, such that you keep it proportional to the horizontal size of the containing div.

Comment: I was looking for information on this phenomenon for a while, and although it is disappointing to find that perspective can’t "scale" with CSS alone, it’s also a huge relief to see something conclusively stating this.